# Converting records from 'YYYY-MM-DD' format to MM/DD/YYYY in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, date, oracle11g, oracle-data-integrator

I am trying to convert a specified column which is in format **'YYYY-MM-DD'** and I need to convert it in **MM/DD/YYYY** as a data warehousing task.

The specified column is in **varchar2** format.

I've been trying to use to_date, to_char but haven't succeeded yet. Any ideas?

Comment: When you say convert, do you mean convert from `varchar2` to `date` data type?

Comment: Why on earth are you storing dates in a `varchar` column? That is a **very** bad idea

Comment: Putting aside the issue of storing dates as text - why do you want to convert your dates from an ISO 8601 format (which can be ordered alphanumerically in date order) to a regional format (that cannot be easily ordered)?

Answer (score 2):

We can try first converting your text dates into bona fide dates using `TO_DATE`.  Then, we can use `TO_CHAR` to convert them to the new format.

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET date_col = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(date_col, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MM/DD/YYYY');
-- and maybe a WHERE clause
```

This being said, it is bad practice to persist your date information as *text*.  Rather, use a proper date or timestamp column if at all possible.  You would be better off creating a new date column, and then stopping after calling `TO_DATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function/procedure, you can try this:

```
some_var := to_char(to_date(column_to_convert,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

It converts first the data to a date, then back to varchar2 using the desired format. Just replace the identifiers accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select to_char(to_date('2018-10-19','YYYY-MM-DD'),'MM/DD/YYYY')from dual;
```

Comment: This answer is identical to what I posted several hours ago.